# How to characterize a Banach space $X$ such that any operator from $X$ to $l_{p}$ is compact?

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $1<p<\infty$. How to characterize $X$ such that any operator from $X$ to $l_{p}$ is compact? Are there any known or new results?

Comment: This seems very open-ended. Perhaps you could provide some examples of $X$ that you already know satisfy this property?

Comment: As far as I know the only characterization is basically trivial:  There is a non compact operator from $\ell_p$ to $X$ iff there is a normalized basic sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and a $C$ s.t. for all finite sequence $(a_n)$ of scalars we have $\| \sum_n a_n x_n \|^p \le C \sum_n |a_n|^p$.

Comment: Any closed subspace of $l_{r}(p<r<\infty)$ satisfies this property. This is famous Pitt's Theorem.

Comment: This paper might have some relevant results: Maslyuchenko, O. V.; Mykhaylyuk, V. V.; Popov, M. M. Asymptotic structure and the existence of noncompact operators between Banach spaces. (English summary)
J. Funct. Anal. 253 (2007), no. 2, 550–560.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** The following proof is valid if one defines an “operator” as a linear function, *not necessarily assumed to be bounded*, between two vector spaces.

I claim that if $X$ is as you described, then it must be finite-dimensional.

To see this, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $X$ is infinite-dimensional. Then, the dimension of $X$ must be at least of the cardinality of the continuum. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis). In fact, one can use [Baire’s category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) to conclude that the dimension of $X$ must be uncountable, but the former result is stronger without assuming the continuum hypothesis. Why one needs the stronger result that $\operatorname{dim} X\geq\#\mathbb R$ will be clear below.) The dimension of $\ell^p$, on the other hand, is *precisely* $\#\mathbb R$ for any $p\in(1,\infty)$. (After all, the cardinality of *all* real sequences is $\#\mathbb R$.) Let’s take a Hamel basis $\mathscr H$ of $X$ and a Hamel basis $\mathscr L$ of $\ell^p$.

By the preceding arguments, there exists a surjective function $f:\mathscr H\to\mathscr L$. Using the fact that basic representations are unique, one can extend $f$ to a surjective linear function $F:X\to\ell^p$. By assumption, $F$ is a compact operator, so it is *a fortiori* continuous. Letting
\begin{align*}
U\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,\|x\|<1\},\\
C\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,\|x\|\leq 1\},
\end{align*}
one has that $F(C)$ is precompact in $\ell^p$, so that $F(U)$ is also precompact. Invoking the [open-mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)), one can conclude that $F(U)$ is a non-empty, precompact open set. But this is impossible, since $\ell^p$, being an infinite-dimensional normed vector space, cannot be locally compact.

Comment: "Operator" means *continuous* linear map.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I beg to differ—interpretations vary. To the best of my knowledge, the most common definition of an operator is a linear function between vector spaces.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth At any rate, I added a warning in the beginning so that the OP can decide whether this interpretation is useful for him/her.

Comment: In my question, "operator"means linear bounded mapping. I am sorry.

Comment: I agree with @JochenWengenroth since the question is posed in the setting of Banach spaces by someone who works on Banach spaces. It is common practice for those who work in the areas of Banach spaces, Banach algebras, Cstar algebra, von Neumann algebras, etc to say "operator" as short-hand for "bounded linear map"

Comment: @DongyangChen In this case, I’m sorry my answer couldn’t help. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @triple_sec Anyway, I thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @DongyangChen For what it’s worth, this argument shows that if $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then there cannot exist a surjective linear continuous operator $F:X\to\ell^p$.

Comment: @triple_sec I think you are wrong. Obviously, there exists a surjective linear continuous operator $F: l_{1}\rightarrow l_{p}$. This is because each separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to $l_{1}$.

Comment: @DongyangChen I mean, **if** $X$ satisfies your condition that any bounded linear operator from $X$ to $\ell^p$ is a compact operator. Then, if there existed a surjective continuous linear operator $F:X\to\ell^p$, then $F$ would be an open mapping (given that both $X$ and $\ell^p$ are Banach spaces) _and_ a compact operator by assumption. But, as I argued above, this would imply that the image of the open unit ball of $X$ under $F$ was a non-empty, precompact open subset of $\ell^p$, which is impossible (in an infinite-dimensional vector space—complete or not—any compact set is nowhere dense).

Comment: @triple_sec You are right. If $X$ satisfies my condition, then there cannot exist a surjective linear continuous operator from $X$ to $l^{p}$. This is due to open mapping theorem.

Comment: @DongyangChen I’m wondering whether this could help you sharpen the characterization of such an $X$ in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29471/discussion-between-dongyang-chen-and-triple-sec).

Comment: @triple_sec the formal identity $i_{2,p}:l_{2}\rightarrow l_{p}(p>2)$ is non-compact and not surjective. There is no surjective linear continuous operator from $l_{2}$ to $l_{p}$.